# Slope with array argument in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pass rows based on criteria to my slope function - a very simple idea, but I can't get it to work.

={SLOPE(IF(G31=G393=0;E31:E393);IF(G31:G393=0;F31:F393))}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your array formula {} and in the answer below are in the wrong place. They should appear on the outside. That and the "," separator.

Comment: Thanks! Care to correct me so I see what you mean? :)

Comment: For my  locale it is {=SLOPE(IF(G31:G393=0,E31:E393),IF(G31:G393=0,F31:F393))}  . The {} appear when you press Ctrl + Shift  + Enter and for yours {=SLOPE(IF(G31:G393=0;E31:E393),IF(G31:G393=0;F31:F393))}

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have no idea how I didn't get it to work as that is exactly what I tried (I added the array marks manually in the question, haha). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error

```
{=SLOPE(IF(G31:G393=0;E31:E393),IF(G31:G393=0;F31:F393))}
```

Comment: I'm running on Swedish language which uses "," as decimal.

Comment: There is a `=` instead of `:` too